# Trying to update sum num for my GridView with my access Database have problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, sql-update

I want to Update An Number of goals That a Player Scored so if he scored a goal I want to do an update for his number of goals... I got an Error in my Code And I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me to fix it, please?

## My Asp.net Code:

```
    protected void SoccerTable_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SoccerDataBase.mdb";
    using (OleDbConnection sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        string queryStr = "SELECT Achievement FROM SoccerAchievements WHERE @id";
        OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(SoccerTable.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfGoals", (SoccerTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AchNums") as DropDownList).Text.Trim());
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapt.Fill(ds, "SoccerAchievement");
        DataRow row = ds.Tables["SoccerAchievement"].Rows[0];
        int a = int.Parse("@NumOfGoals");
        string query = "UPDATE SoccerAchievements SET Achievement= '" + a + "' WHERE @id";
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

## My GridView Code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="SoccerTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="ID"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
            OnRowUpdating="SoccerTable_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="קוד שחקן" InsertVisible="False" 
            SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Team" HeaderText="קבוצות" SortExpression="Team" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Players" HeaderText="שחקנים" 
            SortExpression="Players" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="הישגים">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="AchNums" runat="server"> 
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" ImageUrl="Pictures/AdminToolsPics/save.png" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Update" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

My Error: Input string to the same plant daughter.
[image]

Please Help me guys:)

Answer (score 1):

The code `int a = int.Parse("@NumOfGoals");` will never work, since the function `int.Parse()` tries to convert a string to and integer. Sinde the string `@NumOfGoals` is not a string it all, the function will throw an exception.

Comment: So how can i sum this num to my database?

Comment: Which number are you trying to insert in/add to the database?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="AchNums" runat="server"> 
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: im trying to sum this num to my database, the selected value...

Comment: You can access the selected value of the DropDownList by calling `AchNums.SelectedValue`

Comment: It is not id AchNums... Because he is available in GridView itemtemplate...